# How to create subscale scores for 4 subscales of the REI using SPSS?

Tags: spss, sampling

I need to create subscale scores for 4 subscales of the REI: REI_Appear; REI_Hlth; REI_Mood; REI_Enjoy. The items comprising each subscale are as follows:

- Appearance (9 items): 1, 5, 9, 13, 16, 17, 19, 21, 24
- Health (8 items): 3, 6, 8, 15, 18, 20, 22, 23
- Mood (4 items): 2, 7, 12, 14
- Enjoyment (3 items): 4, 10, 25

For example, I have placed  `REI_Appear` in the target variable but then im unsure of what to place in the numeric expression section for it to work?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since this is a question about `SPSS` exclusively, I have marked it for migration to StackOverflow. You might also ask on an `SPSS` list. This site is only for questions about statistics.

Answer (score 2):

There are several important issues.

- Do you want means or sums or some other composite?
- Do any items need reversing?
- How do you want to handle missing data?

Assuming  you want means, there are no items needing reversing, and you want a participant to have  at least 3 items to get a score, then you could use:

```
compute REI_appear = mean.3(item1, item5, ...,  item24).
EXECUTE.
```

where you replace `item1` etc.  with the relevant variable names.

I have an existing post dedicated to the topic of [computing scale scores for psychological tests](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/calculating-scale-scores-for.html) which discusses some of these issues further.